# How to instantiate a variable (?8758) with a local variable?

Tags: coq

My current proof state:

```
 ...
 qu := 1 : Z
 ============================
  (array_at_ tint sh 0 100 (eval_id _busybits rho) *
   array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (keys m x))) 0 100
     (eval_id _keys rho) *
   array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (values m x))) 0 100
     (eval_id _values rho))%logic
  |-- !!(offset_val (Int.repr (sizeof tint * ?8758)) (eval_id _busybits rho) =
         force_val
           (sem_add_pi tint (eval_id _busybits rho) (eval_id _index rho)) /\
         0 <= ?8758 /\ ?8758 < 100 /\ Vint (Int.repr 1) = Vint (Int.repr 1))
```

I can instantiate variable ?8758 with any integer:

> instantiate (2:=1).

```
  (array_at_ tint sh 0 100 (eval_id _busybits rho) *
   array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (keys m x))) 0 100
     (eval_id _keys rho) *
   array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (values m x))) 0 100
     (eval_id _values rho))%logic
  |-- !!(offset_val (Int.repr (sizeof tint * 1)) (eval_id _busybits rho) =
         force_val
           (sem_add_pi tint (eval_id _busybits rho) (eval_id _index rho)) /\
         0 <= 1 /\ 1 < 100 /\ Vint (Int.repr 1) = Vint (Int.repr 1))
```

But when I try to instantiate it with a local variable:

> instantiate (2:=qu).

I receive an error message:

```
Toplevel input, characters 38-40:
Error: Instance is not well-typed in the environment of ?8758
```

Why can not I instantiate it with a variable?

### Edit:

> instantiate (2:=1%Z).

Works just in the same way as (2:=1).

### Existentials: (in response to @Vinz)

> Show Existentials.

```
Existential 1 =
?9091 : [Espec : OracleKind
         sh : share
         m : ArrMapZ
         key : Z
         val : Z
         vkey : Values.val
         vval : Values.val
         H : repr key vkey
         H0 : repr val vval
         H4 : writable_share sh
         Struct_env := abbreviate : type_id_env.type_id_env
         bbarg : name _busybits
         ksarg : name _keys
         valsarg : name _values
         karg : name _key
         startloc : name _start
         indexloc : name _index
         startloc0 : Values.val
         indexloc0 : Values.val
         Delta := abbreviate : tycontext
         MORE_COMMANDS := abbreviate : statement
         rho : environ
         H5 : None <> find_empty m (loop key) 99
         H1 : isptr (eval_id _busybits rho)
         H2 : isptr (eval_id _keys rho)
         H3 : isptr (eval_id _values rho)
         POSTCONDITION := abbreviate : ret_assert
         H6 : Vint
                (Int.repr
                   match find_empty m (loop key) 99 with
                   | Some x => x
                   | None => -1
                   end) = eval_id _index rho
         qu := 1 : Z
        |- (array_at_ tint sh 0 100 (eval_id _busybits rho) *
            array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (keys m x))) 0 100
              (eval_id _keys rho) *
            array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (values m x))) 0
              100 (eval_id _values rho))%logic
           |-- !!(offset_val (Int.repr (sizeof tint * ?8758))
                    (eval_id _busybits rho) =
                  force_val
                    (sem_add_pi tint (eval_id _busybits rho)
                       (eval_id _index rho)) /\
                  0 <= ?8758 /\ ?8758 < 100 /\ ?8759 = Vint (Int.repr 1))] 
Existential 2 =
?9089 : [Espec : OracleKind
         sh : share
         m : ArrMapZ
         key : Z
         val : Z
         vbb : Values.val
         vkeys : Values.val
         vvals : Values.val
         vkey : Values.val
         vval : Values.val
         H : repr key vkey
         H0 : repr val vval
         H1 : isptr vbb
         H2 : isptr vkeys
         H3 : isptr vvals
         H4 : writable_share sh
         Struct_env := abbreviate : type_id_env.type_id_env
         bbarg : name _busybits
         ksarg : name _keys
         valsarg : name _values
         karg : name _key
         startloc : name _start
         indexloc : name _index
         startloc0 : Values.val
         indexloc0 : Values.val
         vindex := Vint
                     (Int.repr
                        match find_empty m (loop key) 99 with
                        | Some x => x
                        | None => -1
                        end) : Values.val
         Delta := abbreviate : tycontext
         POSTCONDITION := abbreviate : ret_assert
         MORE_COMMANDS := abbreviate : statement
        |- semax Delta
             (PROP  (None <> find_empty m (loop key) 99)
              LOCAL  (`(eq vindex) (eval_id _index);
              `(eq vbb) (eval_id _busybits); `(eq vkeys) (eval_id _keys);
              `(eq vvals) (eval_id _values))
              SEP 
              (`(array_at tint sh
                   (upd
                      (fun x : Z =>
                       Vint (Int.repr (if busybits m x then 1 else 0))) 
                      ?8758 ?8759) 0 100)
                 (fun _ : lift_S (LiftEnviron mpred) => vbb);
              `(array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (keys m x))) 0
                  100 vkeys);
              `(array_at tint sh (fun x : Z => Vint (Int.repr (values m x)))
                  0 100 vvals)))
             (Ssequence
                (Sassign
                   (Ederef
                      (Ebinop Oadd (Etempvar _keys (tptr tint))
                         (Etempvar _index tint) (tptr tint)) tint)
                   (Etempvar _key tint)) MORE_COMMANDS) POSTCONDITION] 
Existential 3 =
?8759 : [Espec : OracleKind
         sh : share
         m : ArrMapZ
         key : Z
         val : Z
         vbb : Values.val
         vkeys : Values.val
         vvals : Values.val
         vkey : Values.val
         vval : Values.val
         H : repr key vkey
         H0 : repr val vval
         H1 : isptr vbb
         H2 : isptr vkeys
         H3 : isptr vvals
         H4 : writable_share sh
         Struct_env := abbreviate : type_id_env.type_id_env
         bbarg : name _busybits
         ksarg : name _keys
         valsarg : name _values
         karg : name _key
         startloc : name _start
         indexloc : name _index
         startloc0 : Values.val
         indexloc0 : Values.val
         vindex := Vint
                     (Int.repr
                        match find_empty m (loop key) 99 with
                        | Some x => x
                        | None => -1
                        end) : Values.val
         Delta := abbreviate : tycontext
         MORE_COMMANDS := abbreviate : statement |- 
        reptype tint] 
Existential 4 =
?8758 : [Espec : OracleKind
         sh : share
         m : ArrMapZ
         key : Z
         val : Z
         vbb : Values.val
         vkeys : Values.val
         vvals : Values.val
         vkey : Values.val
         vval : Values.val
         H : repr key vkey
         H0 : repr val vval
         H1 : isptr vbb
         H2 : isptr vkeys
         H3 : isptr vvals
         H4 : writable_share sh
         Struct_env := abbreviate : type_id_env.type_id_env
         bbarg : name _busybits
         ksarg : name _keys
         valsarg : name _values
         karg : name _key
         startloc : name _start
         indexloc : name _index
         startloc0 : Values.val
         indexloc0 : Values.val
         vindex := Vint
                     (Int.repr
                        match find_empty m (loop key) 99 with
                        | Some x => x
                        | None => -1
                        end) : Values.val
         Delta := abbreviate : tycontext
         MORE_COMMANDS := abbreviate : statement |- Z]
```

---

Coq 8.4pl3

Comment: Just a wild guess but is ``1`` a ``Z`` or a ``nat`` in your first instantiation ?

Comment: of Z. I'll clarify it int the question.

Comment: Thanks @Necto. I did some (very simple) tests and I can instantiate with local variables without any error. Maybe you have some implicit hiding somewhere, could you add the output of ``Show Existentials.`` (at the location you would do your ``instantiate``) please ?

Comment: Done. It's quite big: It is generated by VST framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that `qu` is not in your existential variable's context.

You see, every time an existential variable is created, it inherits the current context (a.k.a. environment) and can't be instanciated by a term that contains variables not in that context. This is to prevent some forms of circular reasoning, though I guess in your case it's too strict.

```
Goal forall P, exists x : False, P x -> False -> False.
Proof.
intros.
eexists.
intros H1 H2.
instantiate (1 := H2) in H1.
exact H2.
Qed.
```

You need to define `qu` before creating the existential.

Comment: I think you are right: the order in which things are declared is relevant in Coq (because of type dependency). If you have a look at the first evar, you can see ``qu`` in the context (the things left of ``|-``), but for your evar, the 4th one, ``qu`` is not there. Try to introduce ``qu`` before you introduce the evar ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback. I think your problem is that you don't instantiate the correct variable, but you get a side effect that instantiate ?8758.
If you take a look at the output of `Show Existentials`, you'll see that  ?8758 is not the 2nd variable but the 4th and also that the 2nd has a creepy huge type whereas the 4th is of type `Z`.

Does `instantiate (4 := qu).` solves your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It behaves like `instantiate (2:=qu)`. `instantiate (4:=qu)` gives the same error as the former, and  `instantiate (4:=1)` replaces `?8758` with `1`

Comment: Damnit.. I don't know what's happening here, sorry.